# Remapping keys in KDE (4.8.5, Kubuntu 12.04)

Tags: keyboard, kde, kubuntu

I have been remapping keys via xmodmap commands but this doesn't appear to be very satisfactory on my Kubuntu 12.04. The problem is that when I hibernate my computer and then log back in again, KDE seems to reapply the original settings and the value sourced in .bashrc is lost.

The behaviour I'm trying to change is that configured in the System Settings -> Input Devices -> Keyboard -> Advanced -> Alt/Win key behaviour. I would use that but they don't have the options I want... It must be easily configurable though - if they are doing it there then it must be possible!

Thanks.

(ps. this is not the same as my META problem - I have decided I'm going to stick with VIM :-))

Comment: Could you please specify when the settings are reset? After reboot, hibernation, logout/login or just after some longer time?

Comment: I've updated. It's after re-login after hibernate.